# Google Maps v3, animating polyline between more than two points

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So far on my page I can animate a polyline between two points but I can't figure out how to do it for anything more than that.

**Example 1**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    flightPath.setMap(map);
    flightPathProgress.setMap(map);
    flightPathProgress.setOptions({
        strokeOpacity: 0
    });

    var progress = 0;

    var intvl = setInterval(function() {

        progress += 0.01;

        if (progress > 1) { 
            clearInterval(intvl);
            running = false;
        } else {
            // animation is still running
            running = true;
        }

        // calculate progress
        var progressLatLng = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(postcode_1_lat_lng, postcode_4_lat_lng, progress);
        // update polyline
        flightPathProgress.setOptions({
            strokeOpacity: progress,
            path: [postcode_1_lat_lng, progressLatLng]
        });
    }, 50);
}, 1000);
```

[Example 1 Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeeLbdsd/3/)

If you check the example 1 fiddle (please forgive the `setMarkers`, it needs a lot of tidying up), animating between the first and last points results in a direct line being drawn between them rather than following the path of the four points, which is why I can get it to work perfectly fine when there are only two points.

I considered that I must create some sort of loop to draw a line between consecutive points, e.g. 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 etc. but I can't seem to get it to work (try changing `postcode_4_lat_lng` to `postcode_2_lat_lng`, that's what I'm trying to achieve between all points).

**Example 2**

```
setTimeout(function() {

    flightPath.setMap(map);
    flightPathProgress.setMap(map);
    flightPathProgress.setOptions({
        strokeOpacity: 0
    });

    var points = [postcode_1_lat_lng, postcode_2_lat_lng, postcode_3_lat_lng, postcode_4_lat_lng];
    var i = 0;
    var progress = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var start_point = points[i];
        var end_point = points[i + 1];

        var intvl = setInterval(function() {

            progress += 0.01;

            if (progress > 1) { 

                clearInterval(intvl);
                i++;
            } else {
                // animation is still running
                running = true;
           }

           // calculate progress
           var progressLatLng = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start_point, end_point, progress);
           // update polyline
           flightPathProgress.setOptions({
               strokeOpacity: progress,
               path: [postcode_1_lat_lng, progressLatLng]
           });
       }, 50);
   }
}, 1000);
```

If I try and do it this way I just get an infinite amount of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'k' of undefined` errors.

[Example 2 Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykmum50m/4/)

Comment: I think you can juste make the interpolation yourself

Comment: @sabotero, sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: You're going to get an error when you do `var end_point = points[i + 1];` when you're on the last iteration of the loop. Try changing the iterator to `i < points.length - 1`

Comment: You need to do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html) (animate along the polyline).

Comment: good spot @duncan, I noticed it myself earlier but wasn't getting as far as that to be concerned about it. Thanks for the link geocodezip. 

I've managed to solve it an ugly way, I'll try and get around to posting it incase anyone needs it in the future but there's a lot of improvements that could be done to it.

Comment: @martincarlin87 do you still have the link to your solution?

Comment: @hannah - sorry for the delay, I only just seen your message. I just updated the fiddle, hopefully it will help: http://jsfiddle.net/zeeLbdsd/15/. The code is very repetitive and can be greatly improved but it does work. The only slight bug is that the animation of the progress is the same no matter the distance between points, i.e. a short distance between points will animate at the same speed as a long distance so the short distance animation seems rushed in comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I use a slightly different approach to the animation, based off [this post](https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/animated-paths-with-google-maps/).
Instead of using `interpolate`, you add individual points to the map at set intervals.

Here is the method I wrote to achieve this (Coffeescript):

```
grow_polyline: (path, encoded, interval) =>
    if encoded
      poly_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(path)
    else
      poly_path = path


    full_polyline = new google.maps.Polyline
      path: poly_path

    grow_polyline = new google.maps.Polyline
      path: []
      geodesic: true
      strokeColor: '#e87767'
      strokeOpacity: 1.0
      strokeWeight: 7
      map: @map

    i = 0
    full_polyline.getPath().forEach (latLng) =>
      window.timeouts.push setTimeout ((coor) ->
        grow_polyline.getPath().push coor
      ), interval*i, latLng
      i++
```

Where @map is the instance of the Google Map object

Answer (score 1):

You need:

1. Initialize map
2. Display or add markers
3. Use the [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) to calculate directions between them.
   3.1 If you have multiples markers, you can set them as waypoints.
4. Draw one Polyline and with setTimeout you moves the marker and adjusts the map view.

In other words, the marker is updated for each x seconds inside the polyline and the map is moved together.

I made a example with two markers and the animation between them. [Codepen](http://s.codepen.io/thulioph/debug/aNaBZg)

I hope help you!