# Animating multi-path polylines in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to animate polylines of all types on a custom map that I am building. I can animate a line that's between two points, but I also have some polylines with more than two consecutive points. When I try to animate them the whole line rotates and goes off screen. How am I able to draw out each individual line, if there are more than two points?

```
    // Initializing Paths
    var flightPlan = {
      one: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.119206, -73.132978),
        new google.maps.LatLng(17.1907805, -88.320144),
        new google.maps.LatLng(33.7677129, -84.4206039)
      ],
      two: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.119206, -73.132978),
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.782324, -80.2310801)
      ],
      three: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.4001576, -75.5079229),
        new google.maps.LatLng(21.552925, -85.720258),
        new google.maps.LatLng(29.1055596, -90.19444)
      ]
    };

    // Initialization of Polylines
    flightPath_1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlan.one,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      icons: [
        {
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: '100%'
        }, {
          icon: lineSymbolTwo,
          offset: '0',
          repeat: '15px'
        },
      ],
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      strokeColor: '#f00',
      map: map
    });

    flightPath_2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlan.two,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      icons: [
        {
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: '100%'
        }, {
          icon: lineSymbolTwo,
          offset: '0',
          repeat: '15px'
        },
      ],
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      strokeColor: '#f00',
      map: map
    });

    flightPath_3 = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlan.three,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      icons: [
        {
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: '100%'
        }, {
          icon: lineSymbolThree,
          offset: '0',
          repeat: '10px'
        },
      ],
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      strokeColor: '#00f',
      map: map
    });

    // Draws out polylines
    var drawOut = function(line) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          line.setMap(map);
          // flightPathProgress.setMap(map);
          line.setOptions({
              strokeOpacity: 0
          });

          var progress = 0,
              lineArray = line.getPath().getArray(),
              lineLength = lineArray.length;

          for (var i = 0; i < lineLength - 1; i++) {
            var startPoint = lineArray[i],
                nextPoint = lineArray [i + 1];

            var intvl = setInterval(function() {

                progress += 0.01;

                if (progress > 1) { 
                    clearInterval(intvl);
                    running = false;
                } else {
                    // animation is still running
                    running = true;
                }

                // calculate progress
                var progressLatLng = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(startPoint, nextPoint, progress);

                // update polyline
                line.setOptions({
                    // strokeOpacity: progress,
                    path: [lineArray[0], progressLatLng]
                });
            }, 50);
          }
      }, 1000);
    }



  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I found a similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720158/google-maps-v3-animating-polyline-between-more-than-two-points) but a solution was never posted.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hlmurray91/sqoksLaw/). The blue polyline is displaying the issue, the red line to to the right is showing the animation I wish to achieve on load, and the red line to the left shows what the multi-path polyline should resemble.

Comment: I don't see the problem you describe in your fiddle (in Chrome).

Comment: @geocodezip hmm, I'm in Chrome as well. The blue line is slightly rotating about for me.